# Using i.albedo tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have run the i.albedo tool with Landsat8 imagery as follows:

[image]

However, this gives the following output, with weird values.

Am I doing something wrong or are additional manipulations necessary to obtain a surface albedo value between 0 and 1?

[image]

Comment: Probably, you need to scale each band (multiplying by 0.0001) before using **i.albedo** tool in QGIS.

Comment: Which steps did you follow to derive the surface reflectance (`*_SR_B?`) layers from the original Landsat 8 DN files?